# Giving conditions to Neo4j Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, knowledge-graph

When I query `MATCH (n:label {Name_1: 'A'}) MATCH (n)--(p)--(q)--(r) RETURN n, p, q, r`

[image]

But B receives connection from other nodes aswell, like

[image]

Here I want B to be given only when I query every node connected to B with a query like

```
MATCH (n:label {Name_1: 'A'}), (m:label {Name_1: 'F'}), (o:label {Name_1: 'E'})
MATCH (n)--(p)--(q)--(r)
RETURN n, m, o, p, q, r
```

Can we attain it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly: You just want a query that matches the graph in the second figure? Or am I missing something?

You can `MATCH` more complex patterns that are not just linear:

```
MATCH (n:label {Name_1: 'A'}), (m:label {Name_1: 'F'}), (o:label {Name_1: 'E'})
MATCH (n)--(p)--(q)--(r),
      (p)--(m),
      (p)--(o)
RETURN n, m, o, p, q, r
```

Or more compact:

```
MATCH (n:label {Name_1: 'A'})--(p)--(q)--(r),
      (p)--(m:label {Name_1: 'F'}),
      (p)--(o:label {Name_1: 'E'})
RETURN n, m, o, p, q, r
```